# angularjs limit html editor data to some limit

Tags: angularjs

Here is response that i am getting from Api
data :

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}-->
</style>
<span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,Arial;font-style:normal;color:#000000;" 
      data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;http://www.gov.ph/2001/08/11/republic-act-no-9155/\n\n\nhttp://deped.gov.ph/orders/do-13-s-2016\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://www.gov.ph/1991/10/10/republic-act-no-7160/&quot;}"
      data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:2112445,&quot;3&quot;:[null,0],&quot;5&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;5&quot;:[null,2,0]},{&quot;1&quot;:0,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;3&quot;:3},{&quot;1&quot;:1,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;4&quot;:1}]},&quot;6&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;5&quot;:[null,2,0]},{&quot;1&quot;:0,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;3&quot;:3},{&quot;1&quot;:1,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;4&quot;:1}]},&quot;7&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;5&quot;:[null,2,0]},{&quot;1&quot;:0,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;3&quot;:3},{&quot;1&quot;:1,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;4&quot;:1}]},&quot;8&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;5&quot;:[null,2,0]},{&quot;1&quot;:0,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;3&quot;:3},{&quot;1&quot;:1,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;4&quot;:1}]},&quot;10&quot;:1,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;14&quot;:[null,2,0],&quot;15&quot;:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;16&quot;:11,&quot;24&quot;:[null,0,3,0,3]}"
>http://www.gov.ph/2001/08/11/republic-act-no-9155/<br>
  <br><br>http://deped.gov.ph/orders/do-13-s-2016<br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br>http://www.gov.ph/1991/10/10/republic-act-no-7160/
</span>"
```

All above is data i am getting from api

so i just want show 300 character then .... 
For show more or less function

Please help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Are you get the whole of that response as a string? 2. Is the code that you want us to help you with a) to show only 300 characters from the result from the api b) to show only 300 characters from the result of the api and also the code for the show more/hide button?

Comment: i found solution by first removing html element then set the limit of character by 300.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Your HTML**

```
    <div ng-app="yourAppName">
        <div ng-controller="YourControllerName">
            <p ng-show="showLink">{{lngStr|limitTo:300}}
                <a href="" ng-click="showMore()">show more</a>
            </p>
            <p ng-hide="showLink">{{lngStr}}
                <a href="" ng-click="showMore()">hide</a>
            </p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Your Controller**

```
angular.module("yourAppName", ["your", "dependencies"])
.controller("YourControllerName", function ($scope) {
    $scope.lngStr = the_Very_Long_String_You_Retrieve_From_Your_Api;
    $scope.showLink = true; // Set the showLink to show onLoad
    $scope.showMore = function () {
        $scope.showLink = !$scope.showLink;
    }
})
```

I'll edit this into a plunker when I have a better internet connection.